# Error:'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32' SQL VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 20
    TextBox1.Text = i
Next
```

In this code, `textbox1` reads 1 to 20 numbers using 'For' 'Next' loop like that I want to read database table values into textbox1.

Could someone help me to read SQL data from a SQL database into `textbox1`? I am new to SQL and VB.NET. Thank you.

```
 Dim table As New PdfPTable(4)
    table.TotalWidth = 416.0F
    table.LockedWidth = False
    Dim widths As Single() = New Single() {1.0F, 2.0F, 3.0F, 4.0F}
    table.SetWidths(widths)
    table.HorizontalAlignment = 0
    table.SpacingBefore = 20.0F
    table.SpacingAfter = 30.0F
    Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Table Batch"))
    cell.Colspan = 4
    cell.Border = 0
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1
    table.AddCell(cell)
    Dim connect As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB;Initial Catalog=Attendance;Integrated Security=True"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connect)
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
        Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("D:\pdf\" & TextBox1.Text & ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
        pdfDoc.Open()
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT ID,Name,Class,Date FROM stuattrecordAMPM where ID=@ID"
        Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                While i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim sy As String = dt.Rows(i).Item(0)
                    i = i + 1
                End While
                command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
                command.Parameters("@ID").Value = TextBox1.Text
                adapter.Fill(dt)
                TextBox1.Text = dt(0)(0)
                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    Using rdr As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                        While rdr.Read()
                            table.AddCell(rdr(0).ToString())
                            table.AddCell(rdr(1).ToString())
                            table.AddCell(rdr(2).ToString())
                            table.AddCell(rdr(3).ToString())
                        End While
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
                pdfDoc.Add(table)
                pdfDoc.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

I am getting the error 'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.'
I created this code for saving all the records in pdf using textbox 'ID' as pdf doc name.
Without using 'sqldataadapter' when I put ID manually in textbox Its saving the doc., but when I use 'sqldataadapter' to save pdf doc. automatically using `TextBox` I'm getting an error:'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.'. Could someone help to resolve the issue. Thank you...

Comment: Reading data from a database and populating a `TextBox` are two different things and not directly related. One of the biggest reasons that beginners can't solve problems is because they try to solve multiple problems as though they are one. If you want to retrieve data from a database, learn how to retrieve data from a database and then do it. If you encounter a SPECIFIC issue while doing that, explain that specifically.

Comment: Also, what's the point in putting 20 different values into a `TextBox` when each replaces the previous and the user will only ever see the last one?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is literally thousands of examples and tutorials on reading data from SQL based databases systems.  There are even many tools (ORM) that will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you.  Maybe start with something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/accessing-data

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Once Check it out my code I tried reading data from a database and populating into TextBox  to save the pdf doc., while doing this I'm getting an error 'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.'. Could you help me on this issue to resolve. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```vb
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
command.Parameters("@ID").Value = TextBox1.Text
```

you specify that the data type for the parameter is `Int` but then you assign a `String` to its `Value`. If the value is supposed to be an integer then assign an integer. If the value is supposed to be a string then specify that when setting the data type. I don't know what the contents of that `TextBox` is but, if you want to use it as a number, it had better be a valid representation of a number and you should convert it explicitly. Also, don't create a parameter on one line and then set it on the next. Do it all in one line, e.g.

```vb
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
```

Mind you, you shouldn't need to convert the `Text` there because you really to have already used `Integer.TryParse` to validate the input and, if it's valid, assigned the result to a variable. You would then use that variable in this code.

If the parameter should be a string then you should specify the appropriate column width too:

```vb
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
```